# WebGL en apps para android con ionic3

Tags: android, ionic, webgl, three.js

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion para android con Ionic 3. Tengo un juego que usa `babylon.js` y otro aparte que usa `three.js`.

Testeando la app en dispositivos con Android 5.11 o interior, la parte de `three.js` no anda mientras que Babylon sí. Three me da este error:

> webGL not supported

Y si pongo en la consola:

```
document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl")
```

Me da como resultado `NULL`, lo cual tiene sentido.

Babylon anda perfecto, pero con:

```
 document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl")
```

También me devuelve `NULL`. Pero si `pongo engine.webGLversion` me devuelve `2`.

En Android 6 o 7 todo anda bien:

```
document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl")
```

Retorna algo que tiene sentido, y tanto three como babylon dicen que usan webgl.

Leyendo por ahi me enteré q el webview de android (chrome) bloquea webgl para android 5.11 o inferior. Por lo cual tiene sentido q three ande bien en android 6 y 7.

Instalé el plugin Crosswalk para ionic y todo se solucionó aunq yendo bastante mas lento.

La duda que me queda es si:

1. Babylon tiene un CanvasRenderer, el cual usa cuando no encuentra webgl
2. Babylon tiene poderes especiales y puede usar de alguna forma webgl cuando Three no puede

Alguien pasó por lo mismo y pudiera arrojar algo de luz sobre el asunto?

Comment: Hola, al parecer ya viste la documentación y te enteraste del comportamiento en distintas versiones de Android, pero cual es realmente tu duda?

Comment: la duda es porqué babylon anda y threejs no, en estas circunstancais